# Wordpress: show only top 3 posts from 3 categories in order on front page

Tags: wordpress, loops, categories, posts

I would like to display only the top 3 posts from 3 selected categories on home page. All category pages can display the default 10 as usual.

Here is the query I've tried which doesn't work:

`$the_query= new WP_Query( 'cat=1,2,3&posts_per_page=3' );`

And the loop:

```
if ( $paged == 1 ) {
    get_template_part( 'includes/featured' );
} else {
    $page_title = sprintf( __( 'Recent Posts - page %d', 'opti' ), $paged );
}

if ( have_posts() ) {
?>

<div id="recent-posts" class="<?php echo $recent_colwidth; ?>">
    <h3><?php echo $page_title; ?></h3>

    <ul id="recent-excerpts">
<?php

    while( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        if ( $post->ID != $ignore_post ) {
            get_template_part( 'content', 'home-loop' );
        }
    }
?>
    </ul>
<?php
    get_template_part( 'includes/pagination' );
?>
```

Just need a little help meshing these together. I would also like the posts to display the category next to the author if possible.

Comment: you will have to use WP_Query three times, one for each category.

Answer (score 0):

Add $the_query with your loop functins, like:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=1,2,3&posts_per_page=3' );
if ( $paged == 1 ) {
    get_template_part( 'includes/featured' );
} else {
    $page_title = sprintf( __( 'Recent Posts - page %d', 'opti' ), $paged );
}

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
?>

<div id="recent-posts" class="<?php echo $recent_colwidth; ?>">
    <h3><?php echo $page_title; ?></h3>
    <author><?php the_author()?></author>
    <div><?php the_category(', '); ?></div>
    <ul id="recent-excerpts">
<?php

    while( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        if ( $post->ID != $ignore_post ) {
            get_template_part( 'content', 'home-loop' );
        }
    }
?>
    </ul>
<?php
    get_template_part( 'includes/pagination' );
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that - it defaults back to the top ten from all categories mixed up running in order published.

Comment: Would it be possible to modify this code? I can get it to show the 3 categories and limit the posts, but not in the order I want ... 

`// Only top 3 posts from selected 3 cats
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'ad_filter_categories');
function ad_filter_categories($query) {
    if ($query->is_main_query() && is_home()) {
        $query->set('cat','1,2,3');
  $query->set('posts_per_page', 9);
    }
}`

Comment: It seems this is not possible without a plugin then as there is no way to specify posts_per_category - it always uses posts_per_page which is no good.